# Android: Released vs Debug Fingerprint (Sha1)

Tags: android, sha1

I was trying to obtain my Sha1 fingerprint for release and debug. Fortunately, I was able to obtain the debug version code through

> keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Name.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

I was wondering how I would get the release? I tried

> keytool -list -alias androidreleasekey -keystore C:\Users\Name.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

but unfortunately it came out as `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <androidreleasekey> does not exist.`

*Actually my result may have been my released key store since I already built it as released app... I'm not entirely sure though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find the location of the release keystore file and the name of the alias that you used to build your app.

To do this in Android Studio select **Build > Generate Signed APK**. You should see a dialog similar to below.

[image: generate signed apk]

Get the location of the full file path for the release keystore from the **Key store path**. Then use this path along with the **Key alias** that is listed to get the SHA1 as you tried previously:

> keytool -list -alias myappsalias -keystore
>   C:\users\dell-laptop\AndroidStudioProjects\myapp\myapp_release.keystore -storepass android -keypass android